# How to resolve ruta script errors from GermanNovel example project (dkpro with ruta)?

Tags: uima, ruta, dkpro-core

1. I imported the **GermanNovel** example project (downloaded basically from one of the uima-ruta releases at https://github.com/apache/uima-ruta/releases) into eclipse as a maven project. I imported it as maven  because I found a pom.xml file.
2. I find an error in the Main.ruta script stating, 
   **"GeneratedDKProCoreTypes" not found**,
   but GeneratedDKProCoreTypes.xml exists in the descriptor folder.
3. If I change the version of **de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-asl** dependency's version from **1.5.0** to **1.7.0**, then the class **TreeTaggerPosLemmaTT4J** is not found. Is it deprecated or something ? Should I be using some other class(es) and type(s) instead ?

**Main.ruta**

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;

IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos FROM GeneratedDKProCoreTypes AS pos;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Lemma FROM GeneratedDKProCoreTypes;

UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.StanfordSegmenter;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger.TreeTaggerPosLemmaTT4J;

SCRIPT uima.ruta.example.Name;

Document{-CONTAINS(pos.POS)} -> {
    Document{-> SETFEATURE("language", "de")};
    Document{-> EXEC(StanfordSegmenter)};
    Document{-> EXEC(TreeTaggerPosLemmaTT4J, {pos.POS})};
};

Document{-> CALL(Name)};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TreeTaggerPosLemmaTT4J` was renamed to `TreeTaggerPosTagger`.

See also the [DKPro Core 1.7.0 component list](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.7.0/components/).

Additional aggregate information from Peter's comments:

The example project uses maven only for the dependency management. The ruta scripts are built without maven because the project was created before ruta supported maven. If you copy the stuff to another maven project, the type system need to be located in the root of the classpath, e.g., src/main/resources

The line IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos FROM GeneratedDKProCoreTypes AS pos; needs to include the package the type system is located in. If the xml file is located at src/main/resources/my/package, then the line should look like ... FROM my.package.GeneratedDKProCoreTypes AS pos
*Disclosure: I am a DKPro Core developer.*

Comment: Thanks Rec ! Why is "GeneratedDKProCoreTypes" not found ? Also, I'm not able to run the example project directly. I had to copy the scripts, wordlists and .xml files (engine & typesystem) into "resources" folder of another Maven project (my existing project) and run them dynamically from a Java class. However, "GeneratedDKProCoreTypes" is not found in either case.

Comment: The example project uses maven only for the dependency management. The ruta scripts are built without maven because the project was created before ruta supported maven. If you copy the stuff to another maven project, the type system need to be located in the root of the classpath, e.g., src/main/resources

Comment: Ya I've placed all the script, wordlist and xml (engine & typesystem) files including GeneratedDKProCoreTypes in the src/main/resources (in the package com.textjuicer.ruta.date) only. I already have another simple ruta script running fine in the maven project. Is there a sample running project of this kind available ?

Comment: The original question has been answered. For further questions, please mark this answer as accepted and create a new question for your new problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what I meant in my last comment was that my first and main issue regarding the compilation error, "GeneratedDKProCoreTypes not found" still persists inspite of placing the typesystem in src/main/resources. That's why I asked for a sample if any. Plz help me resolve this issue !

Comment: The line `IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos FROM GeneratedDKProCoreTypes AS pos;` needs to include the package the type system is located in. If the xml file is located at `src/main/resources/my/package`, then the line should look like `... FROM my.package.GeneratedDKProCoreTypes AS pos`

Comment: IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos FROM com.textjuicer.ruta.date.GeneratedDKProCoreTypes AS pos;
 IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Lemma FROM com.textjuicer.ruta.date.GeneratedDKProCoreTypes;

Comment: Error in short
-----------------
Cannot resolve imports in GeneratedDKProCoreTypes

Caused by: org.apache.uima.util.InvalidXMLException: An import could not be resolved.  No file with name "GeneratedDKProCoreTypes.xml" was found in the class path or data path. (Descriptor: <unknown>)

Comment: Peter replied with regards to that error message two comments above. Probably the type descriptor is still not in the right folder or the folder is not on the classpath. You could try providing a screenshot of the project explorer for more details.

Comment: Thanks Peter & Rec !! Error Resolved !! I copied the GeneratedDKProCoreTypes.xml to the root of the classpath (src/main/resources) from src/main/resources/com/textjuicer/ruta/date. Even though I prefixed the package name com.textjuicer.ruta.date to GeneratedDKProCoreTypes, the error resolved only after copying it to src/main/resources/. I don't know the reason, but it happenned this way. I must be missing to notice something. Anyways, the older issues are resolved and am facing some new issues, which I shall ask as a new question. Thanks !

Comment: Great! Would be nice if you would then accept the answer - and please if you have multiple problems ask them in separate questions such that they can be separately answered (potentially by different people) and everyone get's their scores ;)